# no correct traffic behaviour opendaylight beryllium

Tags: ping, mininet, opendaylight

i have a **mininet** network and i connected it with an **opendaylight** controller *(distribution-karaf-0.4.2-Beryllium-SR2)*. 
I'm working on ubuntu 15.10 *(Desktop version)*.

In the beryllium controller I installed the following features:

```
feature:install odl-restconf odl-l2switch-switch odl-mdsal-apidocs odl-dlux-core odl-dlux-all
```

When I **ping** an host from another host the behaviour of the controller is not correct because i see **traffic in all the ports of the switches**, like a flooding while I expect traffic only trough the ports that interest the path.

For example:

```
h2 ping h5
```

[byte counters increase in all the ports](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3zapH.png)

**Why I have this behaviour?**

**How can I fix it to have the normal traffic going through the interested ports?**

P.S.
I also tried the same procedure with other releases (Lithium and Helium) and I got exactly the same result. While with the firts **(deprecated) Hydrogen** release I obtain a **normal behaviour** with the traffic going trough the specific ports of the path.

Comment: Are you shure there is no other process creating traffic in your mininet?

Comment: I verified with wireshark and i found a lot of LLDP packets going through all the ports. Probably with openflow 1.3 we have this behaviour (instead with hydrogen controller LLDP packets are not so much). Anyway the problem is solved. thank you for your comment.

Comment: You are welcome. It is not weird we have some variation migrating to a new version. Keep in mind to test your code when you migrate it.